# Can i use youtube api with Iframe without using Iframe id to get palying status?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-api

Can i use youtube api with Iframe without using Iframe id to get palying status ?
I want to use video id instead of iframe id.

Answer (score 0):

When setting up your Player object, you need to pass, as the first parameter, either:

1) the ID of the element (the iframe if it's already embedded, or of another element if you are replacing an element on the page with your player) OR
2) A DOM node that represents the element.

So if you don't have the iframe ID, you'll need to use some method to identify the DOM node ... whether that be with a jQuery selector, parsing element src attributes with regex, whatever.

In other words, there isn't an exposed way to just pass in a videoID and have the player API find an iFrame that happens to be sourcing that videoID; you'd have to write such a function yourself.